# Java BufferedImage Slideshow

Tags: java, rendering, slideshow, bufferedimage

i am trying to write a small slideshow application in java.
What works so far:

- Load the images from the drive
- Pick images randomly and don't pick one twice
- render the image in fullscreen

However, i display a new image every 3 seconds. Rendering the new image looks crappy becuase the display flickers while rendering loading the new image.
I haven't found a way to deal with that problem. I like to to a cool animation like "slide to the left and let the new image slide in from the right side" or "fade the old image out and the new one in".

Here is my rendering code so far:

```
private Frame frame;
private Component oldComponent = null;
private void display(final File file) throws IOException {
    Component c = new Component() {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }
    };

    if(oldComponent != null)
        frame.remove(oldComponent);

    frame.add(c);

    oldComponent = c;

    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment
            .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    gs.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
    frame.validate();
}
```

As you can see, i create a new component and remove the old one, if there has been one.
I'm happy about any information code or links.

Thanks in advance!
Michael

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: I am sorry that i did not make this clear enough. The questions are: Is that the right aproach to achieve what i want? Is there a better way to implement a slide show in Java? How can i get a smooth transition between images like fade out, fade in or just no flickering?